# Ebay php API AddItem or AddFixedPriceItem call with MoneyXferAcceptedInCheckout and BestOfferDetails

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, ebay-api

I am building a script to place a listing on eBay. I am a having problem with following the BestOffer and bank transfer checkout info features.

The first piece of Soap XML string follows. It is parsed correctly by api server, but the best offer is not enabled on the product:

```
<BestOfferDetails> 
  <BestOfferEnabled>true</BestOfferEnabled>
</BestOfferDetails>
<ListingDetails>
  <MinimumBestOfferMessage>Sorry too low</MinimumBestOfferMessage>
  <MinimumBestOfferPrice currencyID=\"EUR\">15</MinimumBestOfferPrice>
</ListingDetails>
```

This elseway is said it's not recognized as a node, and I need it to make faster operations of checkout

```
<PaymentMethods>MoneyXferAcceptedInCheckout</PaymentMethods>
```

Has anybody had experience working with these features?

Comment: Is it actually `currencyID=\"EUR\"` instead of `currencyID="EUR"`?

Comment: I escaped them as I use xml soap so it's =\"EUR\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a bug. I strongly recommend you to ask this question on [eBay developer support](http://developer.ebay.com/community/forums/)

Comment: yes in effect it's more or less a bug. Using revise item instead of revise Fixed Price works